# Редактирование cache.ccf в Томкате Set maxKeySize to: '5000'

Tags: tomcat, кэширование

Есть такой параметр в настройках томката: `Set maxKeySize to: '5000'`,
описанный тут:

[Indexed Disk Auxiliary Cache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/IndexedDiskAuxCache.html)

Но я не смог найти файл, где редактируется этот параметр. В описании написано, что файл называется `cache.ccf`

А где он лежит в скаченном томкате? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По вашей ссылке - [Indexed Disk Auxiliary Cache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/IndexedDiskAuxCache.html) - написано следующее:

> Configuration is simple and is done in the auxiliary cache section of the `cache.ccf` configuration file. In the example below, I created an Indexed Disk Auxiliary Cache referenced by `DC`. It uses files located in the "DiskPath" directory.

т. е. этот файл нужно **создать самому**. Вопрос - где? Откроем другую закладку с того же сайта - [Configuring the Local Cache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/LocalCacheConfig.html) - там написано:

> The classpath should include the directory where this file is located or the file should be placed at the root of the classpath, since it is discovered automatically.

т. е. путь к этому файлу нужно поместить в переменную `classpath`, либо, на сколько я понял, в каталог `bin` самого `tomcat`.